# October CMS Components or Partials

Tags: php, html, octobercms

Good day,

We have a site set up in October CMS.

The design, in pure HTML, is all ok now.

Now our project owner wants the website to have *non tech editable components* meaning, they want the text inside the tags to be editable, but not affect any html tag.

So, given this consideration, do I make partials or components?

Comment: You can use Static pages for this instead. checkout this doc and tutorial https://octobercms.com/blog/post/static-pages-content-blocks-and-placeholders and http://octobercms.com/plugin/rainlab-pages read its docu you get idea how you can make your content dynamic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this would be a solution http://octobercms.com/plugin/rainlab-editable